# Can gradient descent work iteratively instead of simultaneously?

Tags: regression, classification, regression-coefficients, gradient-descent, weights

When multivariate gradient descent is updating weight of single feature, why doesn't it project this new weight when updating weights of next features?

Let's say we have this example of gradient descent:
[image]

When *θj* is updated we use vector of all weights *hθ* in the formula. My question is: why we dont update  *hθ* after updating each feature weight?

Let me show an example:

1. we have vector of weights *hθ* which is following: *[0.1, 0.3, 0.5]*
2. we update first weight *0.1*. When updating this weight, we use this vector *hθ* is used in the formula. Lets say our new value for first weight is *0.2* after update.
3. Now we should update second value, but as I understand it, usually we use the vector *[0.1, 0.3, 0.5]* as *hθ* in the formula. But wouldnt it be better to change *hθ* to *[0.2, 0.3, 0.5]* when updating the second weight?

I understand that this would made whole algorithm depending on order of features, but we could for example just shuffle randomly the order in which we update on each epoch to make it more 'order independent'.